# React Native ignore SSL errors

Tags: react-native, ssl, axios

I have an API where it has HTTPS protocol, I am able to get the data from the post but when I try the same with Axios in react-native it throws "Network Error".

And one more point here is, the SSL is not secure, I tried to use the API URL on the chrome browser and it used to show Not Secure on the search bar.

Could anyone please suggest how to ignore the SSL error in react native?

Comment: Don't ignore HTTPS errors! They're there for a reason. Fix the server instead.

Comment: for time being is there a way to bypass in react native ?